# Batch Script - findstr overwrite csv file with result

Tags: batch-file

I am using batch scripting.

I want to filter out the rows containing a specific string in my sss_output.csv file and overwrite that same file with the result.

Below, I have the following code:

```
@echo
cd C:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin
jmeter.bat -n -t C:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\SessionManagement.jmx -l C:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\sss_output.csv
findstr /c:"WebDriver Sampler" sss_output.csv > sss_output.csv
```

After running executing this script, the jmeter.bat statement gets executed and gets the expected results. However, the second line fails to filter out the rows containing the string "WebDriver Sampler".

If I run the jmeter.bat and findstr line separately in the command prompt, it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `findstr` from the prompt acts this way? My experiment created a new empty file in place of `sss_output.csv`. The classic solution is to create a new file with a completely different name, then `move /y` the new file to the existing file. I believe that the issue is that the same file is opened both for input and output.

Comment: Lets say I am not overwriting the csv file. I'm outputting the result in a different csv file:

`@echo
cd C:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin
jmeter.bat -n -t C:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\SessionManagement.jmx -l C:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\sss_output.csv
findstr /c:"WebDriver Sampler" sss_output.csv > new_output.csv`

The last line does not output the new csv file.

Comment: I didn't know that there was a `findstr.exe` or `findstr` command in [tag:dos]. Please hover your mouse over the tag to see if `DO NOT USE THIS TAG FOR QUESTIONS ABOUT THE WINDOWS COMMAND PROMPT!` suggests anything to you.

Comment: Without a sample of the output (containing both lines-required and lines-to-delete) edited into your original post, we're guess - but adding the `/i` switch to make the `findstr` case-insensitive might be a start.

Comment: Have you considered using `Call jmeter.bat …`? _(to be sure that the next line of the script is returned to upon completion of that command)_.

Answer (score 0):

[Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) is handled *before* commands are executed, so `sss_output.csv` is emptied before `findstr` even starts.

Write the output to a temporary file, then move this onto the target file afterwards:

```cmd
findstr /C:"WebDriver Sampler" > "%TEMP%\sss_output.tmp"
move /Y "%TEMP%\sss_output.tmp" "sss_output.csv" > nul
```